# Оишбка в коде

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Awesomium.Core;
using Awesomium.Web;
using Awesomium.Windows;
using Awesomium.ComponentModel;
using Awesomium;

namespace Mozart_Browser
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int max_tab = 0;
        public Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl[] Browser;
        System.Uri home = Properties.Settings.Default.home;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            newTabs(false, new Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl());
        }
        public void newTabs(bool goHome, Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl contlor)
        {
            max_tab++;
            Browser[max_tab] = new Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl();
            Browser[max_tab] = contlor;
            Browser[max_tab].Size = new Size(545, 283);
            Browser[max_tab].Location = new Point(6, 51);
            Browser[max_tab].Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top);
            if (goHome == true)
            {
                Browser[max_tab].Source = home;
            }
            else
            {

            }
            customTabControl1.TabPages.Add("New Tabs");
            customTabControl1.TabPages[max_tab].Controls.Add(Browser[max_tab]);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот тут

```
Browser[max_tab] = new Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl();
```

Пишет ошибку Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Comment: а подумать? обращаетесь по индексу к элементу массива, и такая ошибка, значит...?

Comment: Ну, видимо Browser[max_tab] не существует. Наверное надо создать Browser, А потом ещё и увеличить число элементов массива Browser до нужного.

Comment: Тут вы его декларируете, но никак не создаёте

Comment: Черт возьми, как я люблю такие вопросы.

Comment: >А как мне его тогда создать

пока на рынке труда со мной конкурируют такие таланты, я без работы не останусь

Comment: ну да ну да

Comment: >Я просто только начал C# изучать

так вот вы и займитесь именно его изучением, глядишь и глупые вопросы отпадут. А пока складывается такое впечатление, что вы пытаетесь писать программу методом тыка, поленившись даже  прочесть первые 20 страниц любой книги по C#

Comment: На первых 20 страниц книги которую и читал было содержание и вступление

Comment: открою вам страшную тайну - их можно было пропустить и начать со следующих 20

Comment: да ладно я и не знал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо:

1. создать объект массивов Browser[]. Объекты создаются оператором new.
2. Но это ещё не всё, т.к. вам нужен массив. Вы используете статический массив, хотя при этом его динамично расширять. Тут два варианта - либо вы создаёте массив объектов Browser с запасом, либо используете динамичный массив, например List.

В первом варианте это

```
...
Browser = new Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl[10]; //на 10 вкладок
...
```

во втором варианте это :

```
public List<Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl> Browser;
...
Browser = new List<Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl>();
...
Browser.add(new Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl());
```

Куда что расставить надеюсь догадаетесь?